# How do I copy uvs between uv sets on a single mesh in blender 2.8?

Tags: uv

New to blender. I have an imported fbx mesh with several uv sets: uvs_1, uvs_2, uvs_3. I would like to copy the uv islands from uvs_2 and uvs_3 to uvs_1 in order to collapse the sets to a single set. In other DCCs (modo, maya) I am able to simply copy my uvs and paste my uvs into other sets. It does not appear to be as straightforward in Blender. Google and youtube are failing me so I'm here now. How am I able to achieve something similar in blender? Thanks!